# Copy selected data from one table to another in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sql-server-2012

I have wrote query to fetch the data.

```
select Terr, Product 
from sdata, md 
where sdata.PSetID = md.PsetID;
```

I want to copy this fetched data to new table.

I tried following query but it didn't work:

```
select * 
into ttl 
from 
    (select Terr, Product 
     from sdata, md 
     where sdata.PSetID = md.PsetID);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: @marc_s I will keep in mind. From the next time i'wll use JOIN syntax. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `alias` name to the `sub-select`

```
SELECT *
INTO   ttl
FROM   (SELECT Terr,
               Product
        FROM   sdata
               INNER JOIN md
                       ON sdata.PSetID = md.PsetID) A; --Here
```

Or simply

```
SELECT Terr,
       Product
INTO   ttl
FROM   sdata
       INNER JOIN md
               ON sdata.PSetID = md.PsetID
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is with the following syntax:

SELECT column_name(s)
INTO newtable
FROM table1;

In your case:

```
select Terr, Product
into ttl
from sdata s
join md m on s.PSetID = m.PsetID
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with the syntax OP missed to add Alias name